# How to retrieve an user's email, first_name and last_name from facebook with fb_graph2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I work on an api application in Rails and from the client I receive the access token and I have to make requests with that token to retrieve email, first_name and last_name. In controller:

```
def create
    begin
      fb_response = FbGraph2::User.me(params[:access_token]).fetch
      user = User.find_by(email: fb_response.email)
      if user.nil?
        user = User.create(email: fb_response.email, first_name: fb_response.first_name,
                           last_name: fb_response.last_name, password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
        status = :created
      else
        status = :ok
      end
      render json: { token: user.authentication_token }, status: status
    rescue FbGraph2::Exception => e
        raise_api_error(ApiError.new(ApiError::INVALID_OAUTH_TOKEN))
    end
  end
```

But `fb_response` only comes with `id` and `name`. (The token has the permission for accessing the email).

Comment: You need to ask for the fields you want. Read the changelog for API v2.4

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to ask for the fields I want with fb_graph2?

Comment: I don't know nothing about FBGraph2

Comment: Did you got answer, I am having same issue

Comment: check out https://github.com/nov/fb_graph2/issues/82. It says you need to pass the fields in fetch method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer:

You need to insert fields in fetch method as follows:

```
 user = FbGraph2::User.me(params[:access_token]).fetch(fields: [:name,:email, :first_name, :last_name])
```

You will get the fields you gave in fields array.